# Is it possible to use rescue with a conditional?

Tags: ruby, exception, rack

Consider a Rack app. I only want to handle the error if we are not running a test:

```
begin
  do_something

  if ENV[ 'RACK_ENV' ] != 'test'
    rescue => error
      handle_error error
    end
  end
end
```

This generates `syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue (SyntaxError)
        rescue => error`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
begin
  do_something

rescue => error
  if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "test"
    raise error
  else
    handle_error error
  end
end
```

This would re-throw the exception if you are not testing.

**EDIT**

As @Max points out, you can be a little more succinct with this.

```
begin
  do_something

rescue => error
  raise if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "test"

  handle_error error
end
```

Comment: If you're re-raising an exception inside a rescue, you don't need to pass an argument: `raise if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "test"; handle_error error`

Comment: the problem here is that it changes the location of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You could always rescue it then then either handle or rethrow depending on your condition

```
begin
  do_something
rescue => error
  if ENV['RACK_ENV'] != 'test'
    handle_error error
  else
    raise error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to raise the error, or it will change the error to `RuntimeError`

My solution would be

```
begin
  do_something
rescue => error
  handle_error error if ENV['RACK_ENV'] != 'test'

  raise error
end
```